# How to edit a big file

Tags: linux, file

Imagine a huge file that should be edited by my program. In order to increase read time I use mmap() and then only read out the parts I'm viewing. However if I want to add a line in the middle of the file, what's the best approach for that?

Is the only way to add a line and then move the rest of the file? That sounds expensive.

So my question is basically:
What's the most efficient way of adding data in the middle of a huge file?

Comment: And just as side note, as you ask about "edit"ing big files: if you were looking for a good editor to do such things, I would point you to VisualSlick. Yes, a commercial product; but in my experience, by far the best editor when dealing with really large files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to insert data in the middle of any (huge or small) file (on Linux or POSIX) is to copy that file (into a fresh one, then later [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) the copy as the original). So you'll copy its head (up to insertion point), you'll append the data to that copy, and then you copy the tail (after insertion point). You might consider also calling [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) (or even the Linux specific [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html)...) but that does not aleviate the need to copy all the data. [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) might be used e.g. to replace [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read2.html) but whatever you do requires you to copy all the data.

Of course, if it happens that you are replacing a data chunk in the middle of the file by another chunk of the *same* size (so no real insertion), you can use plain [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) + [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)

> Is the only way to add a line and then move the rest of the file? That sounds expensive.

Yes it is conceptually the only way.

You should consider using something else that a plain textual file: look into [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) or [GDBM](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdbm/gdbm.html) (they might be very efficient in your use case). See also [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/332071/40065). Both provides you with some higher abstraction than POSIX files, so give you the ability to "insert" data (Of course they are still internally based upon and using POSIX files).

Comment: I think the "of course" part with lseek and write is important.