# How does sqlite3 edit a big file?

Tags: linux, sqlite, filesystems

Imagine a huge file that should be edited by my program. In order to increase read time I use mmap() and then only read out the parts I'm viewing. However if I want to add a line in the middle of the file, what's the best approach for that?

Is the only way to add a line and then move the rest of the file? That sounds expensive.

So my question is basically: What's the most efficient way of adding data in the middle of a huge file?

This question was previously asked here:
[How to edit a big file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237649/how-to-edit-a-big-file/41237690#41237690)

where the answer suggest using sqlite3 istead of a direct file. That makes me curious, how does sqlite3 solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is a relational database. Its primary editing means is btree tables and btree indices. BTrees are designed to be edited in place even as records grow. In addition, SQLite uses the `.journal` file to recover from crashes while saving files.

BTrees pay only log (N) lookup time for any record by its primary key or any indexed column (this works out much faster even than sorting records because the log base is huge). Because BTrees use block pointers almost everywhere, the middle of the ordered list can be updated relatively painlessly.

As RichN points out, SQLite builds up wasted space in the file. Run `VACUUM` periodically to free it.

Incidentally I have written BTrees by hand. They are a pain to write but worth it if you must for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of an SQLite database file is made up of records and data structures to access those records. SQLite keeps track of the used portions of the file along with the unused portions (made available when records are deleted.) When you add a new record and it fits in an unused segment, that becomes its location. Otherwise it is appended to the file. Any indices are updated to point to the new data. Updating the indices may append further index records. SQLite (and database managers, in general) don't move any content when inserting new records.

Note that, over time, the contents become scattered across the disk. Sequential records won't be located near each other, which could affect the performance of some queries.

The SQLite `VACUUM` command can remove unused space in the file, as well as fix locality problems in the data. See [VACUUM Command](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html)